# Pandas return mode if only single value is most frequent

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How to write a condition for returning mode/most frequent value from pandas column.

```
|col|                          
-----               
|C |       
|C|
|C|
|E|
|E|
```

This should return C since it occurs most number of times

```
|col|
-----
|C|
|C|
|E|
|E|
```

This should go to else statement since both E and C occur same number of times.

Comment: `df.col.mode()`?

Comment: I want the output to be the column value and not the mode value. So it has to check if only 1 value occurs the most